# Hibernate one-to-one bidirectional mapping XML

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have 3 tables represented by the following diagram:

[image]

I am trying to build a REST API that when /template is accessed by GET method,
the returned JSON will contain a templateDefinition object, that also contains a template type object. To that end I have created the following mapping files:

Template.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.reporttemplateengine.models">
    <class name="Template" table="TEMPLATE">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="NAME" type="string" />
        <one-to-one name="templateDefinition" class="com.reporttemplateengine.models.TemplateDefinition" constrained="true"></one-to-one>
    </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

TemplateType.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.reporttemplateengine.models">
    <class name="TemplateType" table="TEMPLATETYPE">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="NAME" type="string" />
    </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

TemplateDefinition.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.reporttemplateengine.models">
    <class name="TemplateDefinition" table="TEMPLATEDEFINITION">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="templateFile" column="TEMPLATE_FILE" type="blob" />
        <property name="version" column="VERSION" type="int" />
        <property name="active" column="ACTIVE" type="int" />
        <many-to-one name="template" class="com.reporttemplateengine.models.Template"
            column="template_id" unique="true" not-null="true" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one name="templateType" class="com.reporttemplateengine.models.TemplateType"
        column="template_type_id" unique="true" not-null="true" cascade="all" />
    </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I call the API, Hibernate logs this query:

```
select
        this_.ID as ID1_0_1_,
        this_.NAME as NAME2_0_1_,
        templatede2_.ID as ID1_1_0_,
        templatede2_.TEMPLATE_FILE as TEMPLATE_FILE2_1_0_,
        templatede2_.VERSION as VERSION3_1_0_,
        templatede2_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE4_1_0_,
        templatede2_.TEMPLATE_ID as TEMPLATE_ID5_1_0_,
        templatede2_.TEMPLATE_TYPE_ID as TEMPLATE_TYPE_ID6_1_0_ 
    from
        SYSTEM.TEMPLATE this_ 
    left outer join
        SYSTEM.TEMPLATEDEFINITION templatede2_ 
            on this_.ID=templatede2_.ID
```

It should actually look like this:

```
select
        this_.ID as ID1_0_1_,
        this_.NAME as NAME2_0_1_,
        templatede2_.ID as ID1_1_0_,
        templatede2_.TEMPLATE_FILE as TEMPLATE_FILE2_1_0_,
        templatede2_.VERSION as VERSION3_1_0_,
        templatede2_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE4_1_0_,
        templatede2_.TEMPLATE_ID as TEMPLATE_ID5_1_0_,
        templatede2_.TEMPLATE_TYPE_ID as TEMPLATE_TYPE_ID6_1_0_ 
    from
        SYSTEM.TEMPLATE this_ 
    inner join
        SYSTEM.TEMPLATEDEFINITION templatede2_ 
            on this_.ID=templatede2_.TEMPLATE_ID
```

This is also missing the template type object nested in templateDefinition. I do not know how to achieve this.